# How to prevent Alt+Shift from switching keyboard layout before keyup?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, kde

**Motivation:** In an appplication I'm using, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is taken up by -- well, never mind what, something app-specific. However, on my Linux system (Kubuntu 12.04 specifically), when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> without depressing any of these two keys, the keyboard layout changes.

**Question:** How can I make the keyboard layout change in X only take place if I depress <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, but not if I press another key before depressing them? So that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> only affects the application in my example?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @madhead: Unfortunately not. If I had a lot more reputation I might have offered a bounty. Although... I've learned to tolerate it for lack of an alternative.

Comment: after a quick googling it seems to me that it is a fundamental issue somewhere in XKB (or whatever they use). So, I've switched to `Alt` + `Caps` which is almost the same as `Alt` + `Shift` and isn't used in other places.

Comment: @madhead, a newer [*question*](https://superuser.com/questions/1091407/kde-on-centos-steals-alt-shift-from-applications) linked to this one and seems to have come to a similar conclusion as you did.  Your workaround could be useful to others with the same problem.  Consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: @madhead: It's really not almost the same, it's quite different, and what's more important - it's uncommon and surprising to others :-(

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround

Go in `Settings` -> `Text Entry`. Change the keyboard shortcut from `Super+Space` to something else (ex. `Ctrl+Space`).

Good luck