# KDE on CentOS steals Alt-Shift from applications?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, kubuntu, centos-7, ubuntu-17.04

I'm using KDE on CentOS 7 on one machine and KDE on Kubuntu 16.04 on another.

In both cases I've set `Alt-Shift` to switch keyboard layout. However, in Kubuntu `Alt-Shift-XXX` is still free: I can make use of `Alt-Shift-5` [aka `Alt-%`] in Emacs and `Alt-Shift-o` [aka `Alt-O`] in Krusader, where as in CentOS all app-specific shortcuts featuring Alt-Shift are broken.

This thread sounds very similar: [How to prevent Alt+Shift from switching keyboard layout before keyup?](https://superuser.com/questions/698658/how-to-prevent-altshift-from-switching-keyboard-layout-before-keyup)

I need help to research into this issue.

**Is it GNOME?**

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep '<Alt>'
```

There are no `<Alt><Shift>` combinations. So probably no, it is not GNOME.

**Is it X?**:

```
$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc101
layout:     us,ru
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)
geometry:   pc(pc101)
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)"        };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc101)"     };
};
```

**Edit**

Turns out it's a re-emerging Xorg bug: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865

Now it is featured on Kubuntu 17.04 as well.

Comment: @fixer1234: the bug is sort-of specific to 17.04: I'm using 16.04 on one machine, 16.10 on another and the bug isn't there. It's appears in kubuntu 17.04. Probably the same applies to ubuntu, since `xorg-server` package is the same between ubuntu and kubuntu.

Comment: So you're still looking for some kind of solution or workaround until the bug is fixed?  If so, it would be worth adding that to the end of the question so people don't think the bug information means you've given up on the issue.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to switch to `Alt` + `Caps Lock` or `Meta` + `Space`: these shortcuts are not used across the system.

Comment: I've been using Alt + Caps Lock for a year. I'm not happy about it for obvious reasons.